# Oauth no Azure não abre

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-azure, oauth2

Estou trabalhando com Google Drive API e em localhost a tela de Consentimento - aquela que você autoriza o aplicativo a fazer alterações e visualizar seus dados - abre normalmente em uma nova aba do navegador.

Porém ao subir o projeto para o Azure quando clico no botão que abre esta tela de consentimento nada acontece. Já verifiquei e a ação esta chegando no código corretamente mas esta travando nesta parte pois fica esperando abrir uma nova aba para a pessoa confirmar, e nada acontece.

Alguém sabe se no Azure há algum sistema de segurança que não permite abrir novas abas ou redirecionar para links externos?

Comment: Vc configurou no Google para receber solicitações não apenas de sua máquina, mas também a partir do domínio que sua aplicação está hospedada no Azure?

Comment: Então thiago oque acontece é o seguinte, a aplicação roda em uma maquina virtual no azure. Agora nas configurações do Google, algumas vezes configurei as coisas erradas mas mesmo assim ele abriu a aba da autenticação mas indicando que ocorreu um erro(isto em localhost), porém ao colocar no azure nem esta aba indicando erro abre, agora não sei se este funcionamento(de abrir a aba indicando o erro) é para acontecer somente em localhost ou se no azure ela também deveria estar abrindo, e também não sei se devo configurar algo no IIS para permitir que a aplicação abra essa pagina de autenticação.